# Can't access my HTTP website from EC2 Public DNS Address

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, amazon-ec2, dns, ipconfig

I have created a good amount of these now but this time around for some reason it does not let me visit the address of the Instance which should have Apache Installed from the user data information inputted of `#!/bin/bash yum update -y yum install httpd -y systemctl enable httpd systemctl start httpd`
ec2-3-249-74-75.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com  is my DNS public IP

Have enabled A`uto Assigned Public IP address` within Instance setup

I have a Security Group with `port 80 and 22 open` in Inbound and `All Traffic` for Outbound

I have a VPC with 3 subnets with `DNS Hostname` enabled and on each subnet `Auto-assign public IPv4 address` enabled

Even after all of this it displays Public IP address and DNS address but will not connect me, it just keeps loading when inputted.
If any more information should be required let me know and I will provide.

Comment: Is your instance in a public subnet?

Comment: I manually created them under Subnets with the VPC, how would I check if they're public / private? Thought I would need NAT gateway setup to even create a private one

Comment: Can you SSH to the instance using dns?

Comment: No it does not allow me to

Comment: How do I change it to public or even view that it's private?

Comment: Oh wow I see it now under VPC there's another option to create public and private ones...

Comment: So do you have any idea when I create new instances from my AMI I setup, while the user data is what I mentioned in my post with `Installing the Apache server`, these new Instances created from that AMI have a new user data input and that is to display each of their unique 'Instance ID' within the html page ```#!/bin/bash
echo "<b>Instance ID:</b> " > /var/www/html/id.html
curl --silent http://i-0b3077332eag90f3c/latest/meta-data/instance-id/ >> /var/www/html/id.html``` still does not display the Instance ID of each nor even loads the page now when trying to connect via IP.

Comment: I would recommend making new issue for that, with properly formatted user data, any error messages, what OS are you using, and other relevant info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused by using private subnets for the EC2 instance. For accessing the instance using public IP or DNS, it must be in [public subnet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Scenario1.html).

Answer (score 0):

When I launched **Public IPv4 address** / **Public IPv4 DNS** it took https by default, i set the protocal to http instead and it worked for me